# Error on Convert.ChangeType with Nullable<Int32>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm dynamically building a Lambda expression for a database query (using LINQ). I have a user provided string (e.g. "80") that I need to compare against a field in my database entity object (e.g. Car.Mileage). When I try to construct a comparison Expression, I get a type error.

Car.Mileage is declared as follows:

```
public Nullable<int> Mileage
```

I'm building my query this way:

```
Nullable<int> userProvided = Int32.parse(arg);
Expression constant = Expression.Constant(userProvided);
Expression property = Expression.Property(car, "Mileage");
Expression exp = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
```

This results in an error:

> Expression.Equal is not defined for the types
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.Int32'.

I've tried a few approaches to converting the user's argument, without much success.

- Convert.ChangeType(constant, typeof(Car.Mileage)) failed because Mileage's type is RuntimePropertyInfo. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313590/how-to-use-convert-changetype-when-conversiontype-is-a-nullable-int))
- I've tried Expression.Convert as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975373/expression-for-type-members-results-in-different-expressions-memberexpression) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600685/expression-equal-how-to-compare-nullable-and-non-nullable-fields), but haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: What's the point?  Int32.Parse() does not generate a nullable.

Comment: @hans It does not generate a nullable, but Expression.Equal() complains if one parameter is nullable and the other is not.

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out, largely by re-reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600685/expression-equal-how-to-compare-nullable-and-non-nullable-fields).

I had to use Expression.Convert with the Type of the property Expression:

```
Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Convert(constant, ((MemberExpression)property).Type));
```